# Different performance of openssl speed on the same hardware with AES 256 (EVP and non EVP API)

Tags: aes, openssl

If I run openssl 1.0.1e like this :

```
$ ./openssl speed aes-256-cbc (i.e without EVP API)
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 14388425 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 64 size blocks: 3861764 aes-256 cbc's in 2.99s
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 256 size blocks: 976359 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 246145 aes-256 cbc's in 2.99s
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 30766 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
```

However, if I run it like this :

```
$ ./openssl speed -evp AES256
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 71299827 aes-256-cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 64 size blocks: 18742055 aes-256-cbc's in 2.99s
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 256 size blocks: 4771917 aes-256-cbc's in 2.99s
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 1199158 aes-256-cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 150768 aes-256-cbc's in 2.99s
```

From the [OpenSSL documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/evp.html), it seems that using EVP for the same cipher or not using EVP should not make any difference. Yes I see it consistently. Can anyone please provide an insight? I have googled a lot but could not find anything. I will look through code but not sure if I can understand that part.

Comment: Tom's answer is correct. Also see Dr. Henson's answer on the OpenSSL mailing list at [Verify AES-NI use at runtime?](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Verify-AES-NI-use-at-runtime-td47880.html). In short, the `EVP_*` interfaces are the only way to ensure use of AES-NI (if its available).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In OpenSSL source code, the `speed aes-256-cbc` function calls `AES_cbc_encrypt()` which itself uses `AES_encrypt()`, a function from `crypto/aes/aes_x86core.c`. It is an obvious "classical" implementation with tables.

On the other hand, with EVP, you end up in the code in `crypto/evp/e_aes.c` which dynamically detects whether the current CPU supports the [AES-NI instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set), a feature of recent x86 processors, which allow for vastly improved performance. In OpenSSL code, the `AESNI_CAPABLE` macro does the job (feeding on some flags which are set when the library is initialized, using [CPUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID)).

**Bottom-line:** with EVP, you benefit from the automatic selection of the improved implementation, based on the current CPU model, whereas the non-EVP code directly uses the generic software implementation, which works everywhere, but is slower.

Comment: Great input. Thanks. I did read about AES-N1 while googling but did not connect it with what I was seeing. Thank you. Are there more such issues with EVP / non EVP code and where are they documented - I don't see them on openssl page. Once again,t hanks for the input.

Answer (score 5):

One more thing to notice:

```
$ ./openssl speed aes-256-cbc (i.e without EVP API)
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 14388425 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
$ ./openssl speed -evp AES256
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 71299827 aes-256-cbc's in 3.00s
```

Without EVP API, in 3.00s, processed 14,388,425 (~14M)
With EVP API, in 3.00s, processed 71,299,827 (~71M)

It's obviously processed faster in EVP mode.